# Embedded youtube playback in Crosswalk XWalkView

Tags: android, html, video, tizen, crosswalk-runtime

I am using Crosswalk to develop a HTML5 app. Now i have a problem with playback of embedded youtube videos within the website. I have the same issue testing the website in Chrome browser. There is no issue testing in Dolphin Browser or android default browser (< Android 4.3).

I had the problem in the past also with default android browser, but i can enable playback by setting user-agent to desktop browser. That doesn't work for the crosswalk browser.

If i run the app not on a smartphone but on a tablet it works, also in Chrome with default settings.

Does anybody has an idea/solution to enable video playback on smartphone?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Google's intention was, that every Android Smartphone would have installed the same [basic codecs](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

It seems that not every manufactor of cheap Android Smartphone (from China in this case) meets these requirements (even if Play Store is installed).

[There is a way to display installed codecs on smartphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791473/get-supported-codec-for-android-device/26589396#26589396).

Comment: May i ask how you solved the problem? I maybe have the same problem using android 4.4.2 and crosswalk. Depending on the user agent i choose the video has wrong colors (red/blue is switched) or the video is completely distracted. So, did you change the user agent? If yes, may i know which one you used? Or how else did you solve the issue?